# C6386 warning passing WCHAR param to StringCchCopy - how to resolve?

Tags: visual-c++, code-analysis

This code is giving me the following code analysis warning:

> C6386 Buffer overrun while writing to `m_NID.szTip`.

```
bool CCenterCursorOnScreenDlg::SetTrayIconTipText()
{
    if (StringCchCopy(m_NID.szTip, sizeof(m_NID.szTip), m_strTrayIconTip) != S_OK)
        return FALSE;

    m_NID.uFlags |= NIF_TIP;

    return Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &m_NID);
}
```

The structure in question (`m_NID` is of type [`NOTIFYICONDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataw)). How can I resolve this warning?

Comment: `sizeof` reports the size in bytes, while `StringCchCopy` expects a size in characters.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So I should be using strlen?

Comment: You could use the old C trick of `sizeof(m_NID.szTip)/sizeof(m_NID.szTip[0])`, or the fancy C++ version `std::extent_v<decltype(m_NID.szTip)>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++17 `std::size(m_NID.szTip)` in `<iterator>` is a "modern C++" equivalent to the old `sizeof(m_NID.szTip)/sizeof(m_NID.szTip[0])`. For MSVC, this is supported by the Standard C++ Library even when in the default C++11/C++14 compile mode.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size

With that said, `strsafe.h` is very much the first-generation old-school approach here. A better option is to use the "Safer CRT" functions which are already part of the Visual Studio runtime. You could instead just use `srcpy_s` or `wcscpy_s` both of which have C++ template forms that automatically determine the size of fixed-sized buffers.

If using MBCS:

```
    if (strcpy_s(m_NID.szTip, m_strTrayIconTip) != S_OK)
```

or using UNICODE:

```
    if (wcscpy_s(m_NID.szTip, m_strTrayIconTip) != S_OK)
```